# JOINING multiple tables to a single parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join the data from three different tables into a single view in SQL. The relationship is as follows Parent -> Child 1 and Parent -> Child 2. Child 1 and Child 2 do not have any relationship among them. (See image below)

I tried using a left join and it ends up in the relationship Parent -> Child 1 -> Child 2.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you showed sample data, the query you tried, the result you got, and the result you expected. As it's written now, I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question is about very basic SQL. it has been asked more then hundred times and does not require any effort.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are joining child2 to the parent table?

```
SELECT *
FROM Parent p 
JOIN Child1 c1 on p.colA = c1.colA
JOIN Child2 c2 on p.colB = c2.colB
```

Comment: Yeah, from his question, I think he was trying to join the first child to the parent, but the second child to the first child (instead of the parent).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is the following and depending which set you are after you change the joins ( left, inner, right in combination with where clauses e.g. WHERE c2.b is null). It would be much better to display sample data and desire output instead of a generic venn.

```
 select * from Parent P
 left join Child1 c1
 on p.A=c1.A
 left join Child2 c2
 on p.B=c2.B
```